# How is property value available even before assigning prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Code

```
function Cat(){
}
var c = new Cat();
console.log(c.name);
Cat.prototype.name = 'Snowflake';
```

Output

```
"Snowflake"
```

As seen above i get value `"Snowflake"` for `c.name` even though I logged it before assigning `Cat.prototype.name = 'Snowflake'`

I know that variable and function declaration aren't done at runtime. But assignments and operations are done at runtime. I want to know how did I get the value for `c.name` since `Cat.prototype.name = 'Snowflake'` is an assignment and not a declaration.

Comment: the console can do weird things.

Comment: IIRC, console logging is implemented asynchronously

Comment: [many dupes](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=site%3AStackoverflow.com+console+logging+value+before+it+is+set)

Comment: If you are runing this in the console, all you're seeing is the return value of the assignment operation. Change it to `void (Cat.prototype.name = 'Snowflake')` to block that value.

Comment: @Quentin: I don't believe that's actually a duplicate of the issue here. Consoles don't behave that way when logging primitives like this string, only reference types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running this in the console, all you're seeing is the result of the assignment operation.

As a demonstration, you can use `void` to block the result of the last expression.

```
void (Cat.prototype.name = 'Snowflake');
```

---

Another demonstration is to simply put some arbitrary expression as the last line.

```
function Cat(){
}
var c = new Cat();
console.log(c.name);
Cat.prototype.name = 'Snowflake';
123;
```

Now the console will show `123`, along with an `undefined`, which is your actual `console.log()` call.

---

A better way to avoid confusion (aside from not testing code solely in the console to begin with), is to add some marker text to the log.

```
function Cat(){
}
var c = new Cat();
console.log("The name is:", c.name);
Cat.prototype.name = 'Snowflake';
```

Now you can distinguish between the result of the last expression and the actual log. It should look something like:

```
The name is: undefined
"Snowflake"
```